What is the variance of a regression after t generations?
Suppose we have a regression:
$$x_{t+1} = b x_t + e_t.$$
Taking the variance of each side we get
$$\operatorname{Var}(x_{t+1}) = b^2 \operatorname{Var}(x_t) + \operatorname{Var}(e_t). $$
Now suppose that $\operatorname{Var}(e_t) = \sigma^2$ a constant for all $t$.
Then we have a first order recurrence relation and so we can solve explicitly:
$$\operatorname{Var}(x_t) = \frac{\sigma^2 (1 - b^{2t})}{(1-b^2)}.$$
Unfortunately the book I am reading Gregory Clark's "The Son Also Rises" gives the variance as $\sigma^2 (1 - b^{2t})$. Is my derivation correct?
(NB. For anyone who has the book the page reference is 297. It is not a typo as is made clear by the subsequent text.)

To evaluate the correctness of the Clark formula, consider the case $b=1.$

If $|b|<1$, the process $\{x_t\}_{t=0}^\infty$ is weak-sense stationary, so $\operatorname{var}(x_t)=v$ does not change in time, and it is the solution of $v = b^2v + \sigma^2$, so:
$$
\operatorname{var}(x_t)=v=\frac{\sigma^2}{1-b^2}.
$$
If $|b|\geq 1$ the process is not weak-sense stationary, and the variance explodes in time. If $x_0$ is fixed, then the variance $v_t=\operatorname{var}(x_{t}\mid x_0)$ evolves with $v_t = b^2v_{t-1} + \sigma^2$, for $t\geq 1$, with solution:
$$
\operatorname{var}(x_t\mid x_0)=v_t=\frac{\sigma^2(b^{2t}-1)}{b^2-1}.
$$
I have not read the book, but $\sigma^2(1-b^{2t})$ cannot be a valid variance for a weak-sense stationary process ($|b|< 1$) because it should be independent of $t$, unless $b=0$. Additionally, for $|b| \geq 1$, that formula results in a non-positive variance, which is not possible.

Thank you! The assumption is $|b| < 1$

Hi: The notation subscripting is sometimes important. In this case, it doesn't matter but the model should be written as  $x_{t+1} = b x_{t} + \epsilon_{t+1}$ because the $\epsilon_t$ should be time aligned with the response. Then, once we have this, one can write:
$$\begin{align} x_{t+1} - b x_{t} &= \epsilon_{t+1} \\x_{t+1} (1 - b L) &= \epsilon_{t+1} \\x_{t+1} &= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} b^{i} \epsilon_{t+1-i}\end{align}$$
Therefore,  $\operatorname{var}(x_{t+1}) =  \frac{\sigma^2}{\left(1-b^2 \right)}$.
If one wants the  variance at time $t$, the sum can be calculated for finite $t$.

ADDENDUM: 06-07-2024.
The person asking the question asked for more details regarding alignment of time subscripts in time series regression models.
Suppose one has a model like this (which is what is in the textbook).
$$x_{t+1} =  b x_{t} + \epsilon_{t}$$
So, in this (albeit strange) notation, the $\epsilon_t$ at time $t$ is the only shock to the system that can cause $x_{t+1}$ to change its value at time $t+1$.  Basically, the model is saying that the value of the response at time $t+1$ is only a value of things at time $t$. But everything at time $t$ is known at time $t+1$ so that makes no sense
because some randomness needs to be injected at time $t+1$. Otherwise the relation at time $t+1$ is totally deterministic !!!!!! So, essentially, there has to be something random that can happen at time $t+1$ that can cause the value of $x_{t+1}$ to change its value. Does that make sense?
I'm sure that it's either a typo or a misunderstanding of the author.
This is why the time subscript of $\epsilon$ always has to coincide with the time subscript of the response. I hope that clarifies why one needs the correct alignment of the time subscripts.
ADDENDUM II: 06-07-2024.
One more thing just to close the deal on this: Either of the model notation written below can be used because they are equivalent models
because they mean the same thing:
\begin{align}x_{t+1} &= b x_{t} + \epsilon_{t+1}\\x_{t} &= b x_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t}\end{align}
Notice that, in both cases, the time subscript of $\epsilon$ is aligned with that of the response.

After I wrote above, I saw that Johan did the same thing. my mistake. Ill leave it there but, if I should delete, let me know.

Clark does not align the subscripts. I would appreciate a fuller derivation if you have the time. Unfortunately I have no idea what text I could consult for this sort of problem :-(

Hi peter2108: I'll add an explanation in the answer. If the author has that in his textbook, I'm sure there could be others which could make things quite confusing.  I don't know that book's level so I can't recommend another one. I'll try to find it on amazon and then give you another recommendation.

Hi Peter: I looked at that book and don't know what to recommend as a helper. Maybe look at the time series books by chris chatfield ? Also, kendall and ord have an older book on time series that's a nice introduction. I just looked : It's called "time series" by kendall and ord. Definitely take a look at these books first because they're always expensive and I don't want to recommend a book that you end up getting and not liking. good luck.

Check the date alongside Addendum @mlofton.

@User1865345: Thanks for the date heads up but more than that, you made my answer look so beautiful. I'll go over what you did cause it really makes a difference to the eye. Thanks so much.

For starters, use $$ $$ aka the display mode @mlofton.

I see that. thanks. ( and I used to use align ) but how come in addendum II you didn't use $$.

That is the usage of align environment. For comprehensive but quick tutorial, you can go to the Meta Math.SE page.

thanks much for reference.

Thanks mlofton - I will check out the references.
